# Update database migration using CLI on a mac

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, command-line-interface

I just downloaded a project with Entity Framework installed; the difference with my co-workers is that I'm using a Mac.

I created a docker container for the database, and someone sent me a backup of the database, so I have the database restored and working with the project.

Someone created a new database migration, so I pulled the changes and needed to run the update database command. So I need to use the CLI version because it does not have the Package Manager Console.

So I try to run: `dotnet ef database update 20221229175926_addSalariesTable`

But this is returning:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyContext'. For the different
> patterns supported at design time

My project consists in two layers, one for the web and the other for models and data

Web project name: `Web`

Data project name: `Persistence`

How can I run the update migration correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to navigate to the directory that contains your data project (`Persistence`) in the command line and execute the following command:

```
dotnet ef database update 20221229175926_addSalariesTable --project Persistence --startup-project Web
```

This command tells the Entity Framework to update the database using the migration with the specified name and to look for the migration files in the `Persistence` project.

Comment: That does not work, but you give me an idea of what I need so the correct answer is: `dotnet ef database update 20221229175926_addSalariesTable --project Persistence --startup-project Web`, please update your answer to mark it as correct, Thanks!